# Custom SoftKeyboard: Smileys popup not showing the last row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

i'm creating a custom keyboard and when i longpress the smileys the popup layout cutoff the last row as shown on the screenshot below. How will i make it show the last row?
Here is my **popup_smileys.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="15%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height"
    >
    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="top">
        <Key android:keyLabel="o_O" android:keyOutputText="o_O " android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="&lt;3" android:keyOutputText="&lt;3 "/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="x-(" android:keyOutputText="x-( "/>
        <Key android:keyLabel=":-/" android:keyOutputText=":-/ "/>
        <Key android:keyLabel=":-I" android:keyOutputText=":-I " android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:keyLabel=":-D" android:keyOutputText=":-D " android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:keyLabel=":'(" android:keyOutputText=":'( "/>
        <Key android:keyLabel=":-\\" android:keyOutputText=":-\\ "/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="O:-)" android:keyOutputText="O:-) "/>
        <Key android:keyLabel=":-[" android:keyOutputText=":-[ " android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:keyLabel=":-!" android:keyOutputText=":-! " android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:keyLabel=":-$" android:keyOutputText=":-$ "/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="B-)" android:keyOutputText="B-) "/>
        <Key android:keyLabel=":O" android:keyOutputText=":O "/>
        <Key android:keyLabel=":-*" android:keyOutputText=":-* " android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>
    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key android:keyLabel="=-O" android:keyOutputText="=-O " android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:keyLabel=":-P" android:keyOutputText=":-P "/>
        <Key android:keyLabel=";-)" android:keyOutputText=";-) "/>
        <Key android:keyLabel=":-(" android:keyOutputText=":-( "/>
        <Key android:keyLabel=":-)" android:keyOutputText=":-) " android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

[image: popup_smileys.xml]

Comment: How are you shouing the popup?  It looks like it isn't big enough

Comment: @GabeSechan i've already posted my popup xml above. Also i'm using 50dip for `android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height"`

Comment: increase key height to 65dp for popup